# Consult in Laravel with Many to Many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

[image: related tables]

I need a query either Eloquent or simple SQL that can give me **products** that have the category **technology** and in turn belong to the provider with id **7**

The relationships in both cases are Many to Many where there is a pivot table for each M-M relationship with the id of each parent table

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;


$products = Product
        ::whereHas('categories', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('name', 'technology');
        })
        ->whereHas('providers', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('id', 7);
        })
       ->get();
```

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) of the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using straight sql with a few joins, this looks much cleaner. Also join against product if you need any info there beyond the id, or select just `pc.productId` if you just want the id.

```
select * from provider p
join product_provider pp on p.id = pp.providerid
join product_categories pc on pc.productid = pp.productid
join categories c on c.id = pc.categoriesId
where c.name = 'technology';
```

Personally, I think this looks cleaner in sql. Matching on `pc.id` would be better then on the name, if your setup permits, then you could drop the join to `categories`.

**Edit:**

After re-reading the question, it appears the id is exactly what you want, so for completeness sake:

```
select pp.productId from provider p
join product_provider pp on p.id = pp.providerid
join product_categories pc on pc.productid = pp.productid
where pc.categoriesId = 7;
```